# Python Tkinter selenium chromedriver multithreading error

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

the function works well without multithreading,
but when i use this code

```
button1 = ttk.Button(root, text='btn1', width=3.3, command=threading.Thread(target=click1).start())
```

instead of this

```
button1 = ttk.Button(root, text='btn1', width=3.3, command=click1)
```

I get this error

> Exception in thread Exception in thread Thread-1Thread-2: : Traceback
> (most recent call last): Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py",
> line 932, in _bootstrap_inner   File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py",
> line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()self.run()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
thrd = threading.Thread(target=click1)
button = ttk.Button(root, text='btn1', width=3.3, command=thrd.start) # Do not call start here
```

Note that tkinter does support multithreading. So if `click1` manipulates the GUI, you will get errors.